Using past perfect with just before
Quite often when using past perfect we combine it with past simple. For instance:

I had cooked when she arrived

That's easy for me. I understand that but I also saw sentences like

It hurt like I had never felt before.

I had never had an interview before, so I was nervous.


Both examples were found in my homework sheet given to me by my teacher. My question is: are examples 2 and 3 correct? Maybe there's nothing after "before" because context makes it clear so it's not even repeated? For instance " the ball hit me and it hurt like I had never felt before". So, here would be obvious that I had never felt such a pain in my life before/till I was hit by that ball. Just share your thoughts with me, please.

Your understanding of "before' is correct. When it stands alone, it is understood to mean "before that time"  or "before then" where the time of "then" is derived from what is said.  I went to school for the first time when I was six years old. I had never smelled a school before.  But your example with cooking is not good English.

Merriam Webster: 2
: at an earlier time//
the night before//
knew her before// Please check the dictionary before posting.

"Tim [1] had already cooked dinner [2] when she arrived home."  You can switch the clauses: "When she arrived home, Tim had already cooked dinner." OR "When she arrived, dinner was waiting for her / dinner had been cooked."

#2 Time sequence: It [2] hurt like [1] it had never hurt before.

Examples 2 and 3 are correct, yes. Sadly, your example is not.
The past perfect tense "I had cooked" indicates that the action of cooking was completed before another event (her arrival). However, the simple past tense "when she arrived" is used to describe the other event, but the use of "when" typically implies that both actions happened around the same time. It should really be something like "I had finished cooking when she arrived", or "the food was cooked by the time she arrived".
Typically, when you're describing a sequence of events that occurred in the past, everything has the same tense (eg "I ate my breakfast, went to school, and then walked home"). It gets more complex when you're establishing that events which could have overlapped were completed before something else.
I think you're misunderstanding the word "before" in your examples. In this kind of context, it doesn't just mean one event occurred earlier than the other. In this usage, 'before' means until now. So "I never felt this pain before" means that, until this moment, you had never experienced this kind of pain, or this degree of pain.

Is my explanation for 2 and 3 correct?

@user203412 I've updated my answer to add another paragraph, I think I finally see the confusion.
